# What could possibly lead to the following assembly execution result

Tags: aix, dbx, assembly

I was debugging under IBM AIX with dbx. I was seeing the following:

```
(dbx) print $r4
0x00000001614aa050 
(dbx) print *((int64*)0x00000001614aa050)
-1 
(dbx) print $r3
0x0000000165e08468 
Then I "stepi" my 64bit program which executed the following instruction:
std   r3,0x0(r4)
```

I then immediately checked the content of that memory:

```
(dbx) print *((int64*)0x00000001614aa050)
-1
```

Still -1? I was expecting the content in $r3 should be saved to that
memory. I then manually assigned the value to that address using my
variables:

```
(dbx) print &bmc._pLong
0x00000001614aa050 
(dbx) assign bmc._pLong=(int64 *)0x0000000165e08468
(dbx) print *((int64*)0x00000001614aa050)
6004180072 (which is 0x0000000165e08468)
```

How could that happen?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, somehow, this is "pilot" error.  e.g. you did stepi and then the std instruction was displayed?  which means that that is the instruction it is about to execute -- not the instruction it executed -- at least I think that's right.

I would do some stepi's before and after and make sure I am understanding what stepi is doing.  And, of course, print out the iar, and the instruction at the iar, to verify that dbx is not fibbing on you.